# Navigtionbar Title after select row

Tags: iphone, ios

I created navigationbar, but when I select for example row A מot written in the bar A

how I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you select a row are you pushing a new view controller or do you purposefully want to stay on the same view?

If you want to stay on the same view use the following within your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method...

```
self.title = @"New Title";
```

Or if you are trying to change the view use the following...

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewcontroller animated:YES];
```

Within the newViewController you can use self.title to set the title of that view.

Comment: I use with pushViewController but the bar after selected row is empty